# Why can't I bind to a field on a class in WPF instead of binding to a property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

It appears that in WPF I cannot bind to a public field on an object, but only to public properties.  Is this an intentional design decision on the part of WPF, or am I just getting the syntax wrong?

Here's a sample snippet:

```
public class User
{
  public string Username;
  public string FullName;
  public string DisplayName
  {
    get { return FullName; }
  }
}
```

WPF Snippet:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="User Tool" >
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ListBox Name="listBoxUsers" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}" ItemsSource="..." />
</Window>
```

If I change the Binding Path to Username or FullName, nothing shows up on screen.  Is there an alternate syntax to bind to fields, or is binding only allowed on properties?

Comment: As the answer says, it needs to be a property.  Regardless, it is "better OO programming" (information hiding, etc.) to make your fields private and exposed via properties.  Plus it lends itself to writing things like DependencyProperties, and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, and other good stuff like that.

Comment: The specific case I was working with is using the FileHelpers library to populate items from a CSV, and FileHelpers doesn't seem to support populating quoted fields into Properties, which forced me to use fields.  You're definitely right about Better OO, it was just clunky in this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fields are not part of the [binding source spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

> **common language runtime (CLR) objects**
>
> You can bind to public properties,
>   sub-properties, as well as indexers,
>   of any common language runtime (CLR)
>   object. The binding engine uses CLR
>   reflection to get the values of the
>   properties. Alternatively, objects
>   that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor
>   or have a registered
>   TypeDescriptionProvider also work with
>   the binding engine.
>
> For more information about how to
>   implement a class that can serve as a
>   binding source, see Implementing a
>   Class for the Binding Source later in
>   this topic.
>
> **dynamic objects**
>
> You can bind to available properties
>   and indexers of an object that
>   implements the
>   IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface.
>   If you can access the member in code,
>   you can bind to it. For example, if a
>   dynamic object enables you to access a
>   member in code via
>   someObjet.AProperty, you can bind to
>   it by setting the binding path to
>   AProperty.
>
> **ADO.NET objects**
>
> You can bind to ADO.NET objects, such
>   as DataTable. The ADO.NET DataView
>   implements the IBindingList interface,
>   which provides change notifications
>   that the binding engine listens for.
>
> **XML objects**
>
> You can bind to and run XPath queries
>   on an XmlNode, XmlDocument, or
>   XmlElement. A convenient way to access
>   XML data that is the binding source in
>   markup is to use an XmlDataProvider
>   object. For more information, see How
>   to: Bind to XML Data Using an
>   XMLDataProvider and XPath Queries.
>
> You can also bind to an XElement or
>   XDocument, or bind to the results of
>   queries run on objects of these types
>   by using LINQ to XML. A convenient way
>   to use LINQ to XML to access XML data
>   that is the binding source in markup
>   is to use an ObjectDataProvider
>   object. For more information, see How
>   to: Bind to XDocument, XElement, or
>   LINQ for XML Query Results.
>
> **DependencyObject objects**
>
> You can bind to dependency properties
>   of any DependencyObject. For an
>   example, see How to: Bind the
>   Properties of Two Controls.

Answer (score 3):

It appears it must be a property.

> The source of the binding can be any
>   public property, including properties
>   of other controls, common language
>   runtime (CLR) objects, XAML elements,
>   ADO.NET DataSets, XML Fragments, and
>   so forth.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)